# Calculate how much of a N hour segment is outside business hours 8AM -> 9PM

Tags: javascript

I need a function that given two dates A and B which are always N hours apart (3 or 4, but anything under 10), gives me the total number of hours that fall *outside* of a window 8AM->5PM (or, 800 -> 1700). You can assume that the window is always small enough so that it can only start before 8AM OR end after 5PM. However, I would love to see something powerful enough to consider both cases.

I am developing an overtime calculator for an invoice, and was given this requirement.

I started playing with `getHours()` to see what the hour is on date A, and if it's less than 5, calculate the number of hours difference by creating a new date object with  `A5 = new Date(date.getTime())` and then `A5.setHours(5)` and then `Math.abs(A - A5)`.

If A is more than 5, then I do the same thing but considering 8 the cutoff time.

I would need to use `getHours()` to check if the segment A -> B is TOTALLY outside of the 8AM->5PM window (in which case, return 0).

But... what if the window is 10 hours, 11:00PM to 9:00AM? The first IF would not happen as 11 > 5; the second IF wouldn't either, because 9 < 17.

Surely there are established, *elegant* ways of doing this?

Simple attempt:

```
function c () {
  // var D = 1542695151752 // 14:31
  // var D = 1542684151000 // 11:22
  // var D = 1542645151000 // 00:32
  var D = 1542667151000 // 6:39

  var S = 8
  var E = 17

  var A = new Date(D)
  var B = new Date(D + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 4)

  var Ah = A.getHours()
  var Bh = B.getHours()

  var NE
  var NS

  if (Ah >= S && Ah <= E && Bh >= S && Bh <= E) return (Math.abs(B - A)) / 1000 / 60 / 60
  if ((Ah < S || Ah > E) && (Bh < S || Bh > E)) return (0)

  if (Ah >= S && Ah <= E) {
    NS = A
    NE = new Date(B.getTime())
    NE.setHours(E)
    NE.setMinutes(0)
    NE.setSeconds(0)
  }

  if (Bh >= S && Bh <= E) {
    NE = B
    NS = new Date(A.getTime())
    NS.setHours(S)
    NS.setMinutes(0)
    NS.setSeconds(0)
  }
  return (Math.abs(NS - NE) / 1000 / 60)
}

console.log(c())
```

Comment: This is such a basic question and yet I am going insane with it... grrrrrrr. I know there is a super-easy solution. I know it.

Comment: looks like a good time to use moment.js

Comment: Yeah, do _not_ reinvent the wheel here. Use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Relevant [xkcd](https://xkcd.com/1883/), even if zones aren't your concern right now.

Comment: Happy to use moment! But... does it do what I need?

Comment: It's all fun games saying "Don't reinvent the wheel! Use moment!" And provide zero information about how to actually do so.